# Mockito.any(class) generating invalid use of matchers exception

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am trying to stub a service method with an expected return object with a code that looks like :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(XYZUtil.class)
class SUT {

   @InjectMocks
   XYZController xyzController;

   @Mock
   XYZService xyzService;

   @Test
   public void testDoSomethingController(){

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(XYZUtil.class);

    XYZ xyz = Mockito.mock(XYZ.class);
    PowerMockito.when(XYZUtil.doSomething(Mockito.any(java.sql.Date.class))).thenReturn(xyz); //facing error here
    //other logic testing
   }
}
```

So I am basically facing an InvalidUseOfMatchersException at the line I have commented.
XYZUtil has a static function which I am trying to mock.

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
-> at com.myproject.web.rest.api.test.controller.XYZControllerTest.testdoSomethingController_Success(XYZControllerTest.java:708)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().

    at com.myproject.web.rest.api.test.controller.XYZControllerTest.testdoSomethingController_Success(XYZControllerTest.java:708)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$LastRuleTestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:133)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:110)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:83)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Please include your stack trace.

Comment: @Duncan : Hi Duncan, I have updated the stacktrace. Kindly go through it and share your views.

Comment: @Sourabh Have you looked at this https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic?

Comment: Yes. I did. Did I miss anything? :O

Comment: Basically, I don't understand this: You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.

Comment: Have you tried the `expect` approach? Where is 'You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing' mentioned?

Comment: I can't use the expect approach. I am not using EasyMock.

Comment: In your code you have `xyzUtil.doSomething`, but you mean `XYZUtil.doSomething` correct?

Comment: Yes my bad. Sorry it is XYZUtil only.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I tried the same thing on my code and it worked correctly. Can you share your project so I can check it?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this sort of thing before,

We tend to use other calls to make it work

when(myclass.mymethod(anyString())).thenReturn(outputObject);

So we use

anyString

anyLong

anyObject

etc...

as this stops the need to cast the item.

Another thing we discovered is that sometimes you can accidentally import the wrong version of any()

Make sure its the Mockito one and not the Hamcrest one or other similar one.

Comment: How do you do that for custom classes? Do you pass string to a method everytime?

Comment: of course but usually we try to pass in a known item so its not so much an any()  but a when(myclass.checkDate(testDate)).thenReturn(true);

Comment: For custom object returns we use any(MyObject.class), However we also find that sometimes it will include the wrong any Definition, if you have imported the Hamcrest any then unimport and use the Mockito any.